# Failed to deploy nodejs into azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I am trying to deploy my web apps to azure web apps via azure apps in vscode, but when I try to deploy and I check the results it came out ':( Application Error'. How can I deploy successfully? and I check stream log this is the result :

```
2020-02-21T13:50:37.648590306Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-02-21T13:50:37.651449357Z npm ERR! script@1.0.0 start: `npx babel src -s -D -d dist && node dist/main.js`
2020-02-21T13:50:37.652176195Z npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-02-21T13:50:37.652917034Z npm ERR! 
2020-02-21T13:50:37.653579369Z npm ERR! Failed at the script@1.0.0 start script.
2020-02-21T13:50:37.654141399Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-02-21T13:50:37.660881655Z 
2020-02-21T13:50:37.661645395Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-02-21T13:50:37.662200124Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-21T13_50_37_655Z-debug.log
```

can someone help me ? how to make

this my package json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx babel src -s -D -d dist && node dist/main.js",
    "build": "npx babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "express-recaptcha": "^5.0.1",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "php-serialize": "^3.0.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "streamifier": "^0.1.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-node": "0.0.1-security",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```